# Trying to exclude match when surrounded on both sides by a certain string

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

What I'm looking to do is to modify a regex (JS flavor) to *not* match if the pattern is both preceded *and* followed by the same string.

By way of a simple analogy, say I want to match all instances of `n` that are not both preceded and followed by `e`. So, for example, the regex should not match the `n` in `alkene`, but it *should* still match the `n` in `pen` or `nest`, which only have the `e` directly adjacent to `n` on one side, not both.

Most older threads I've seen trying to find an answer basically say "just use negative lookarounds", but the problem is that `(?<!e)n(?!e)` doesn't match *any* of those inputs - because the lookbehind and lookahead are processed by the regex engine separately, so it considers either condition to be sufficient to exclude the match.

(The real regex is `(?<!¸ª)()(ɣʷ|h₂|r₂|r₃|w|j)(?:e|o|ø|ɑ|i|ɚ|y|u|a)(?!¸ª)` and it's failing to match the `ɣʷ` in `t͡ʃe:h₁dɣʷo¸ªh₂¸ª`, but that makes the problem look a lot harder to explain than it needs to be)

How do you modify a regex to only exclude patterns when they're nested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(?<!b)a(?!b)` pattern here must be replaced with `(?<!b(?=ab))a` or `a(?!(?<=ba)b)`. The point is to call a reverse lookahead or lookbehind from lookbehind or lookahead.

See your pattern fix (without any optimizations) where I took the lookahead, pasted it inside lookbehind after `ª`, reversed the lookahead (i.e. made it positive) and added the whole pattern before `¸ª` in the lookahead to be able to get to the right-hand `¸ª`:

```js
(?<!¸ª(?!(ɣʷ|h₂|r₂|r₃|w|j)(?:e|o|ø|ɑ|i|ɚ|y|u|a)¸ª))()(ɣʷ|h₂|r₂|r₃|w|j)(?:e|o|ø|ɑ|i|ɚ|y|u|a)
```

Or, if you put the lookbehind into lookahead:

```js
()(ɣʷ|h₂|r₂|r₃|w|j)(?:e|o|ø|ɑ|i|ɚ|y|u|a)(?!(?<=¸ª(ɣʷ|h₂|r₂|r₃|w|j)(?:e|o|ø|ɑ|i|ɚ|y|u|a))¸ª)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3EG8NU/1) (and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/3EG8NU/3)).

Whenever your pattern is simple, it is best not to repeat the pattern in the lookarounds, you may usually just use `.` or `.{x}` where `x` stands for the number of chars your consuming pattern part can match. Here, it is not clear how many chars the pattern can actually match, you may probably use `(?<!¸ª(?!.{1,2}¸ª))()(ɣʷ|h₂|r₂|r₃|w|j)(?:e|o|ø|ɑ|i|ɚ|y|u|a)`, but I do not have any edge cases to test against.

Enhancing this further may yield `(?<!¸ª(?!.{1,2}¸ª))()(ɣʷ|[hr]₂|r₃|w|j)([eoøɑiɚyua])` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/3EG8NU/2)).